# What is the difference between "oriented for" and "oriented towards"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions

I found conflicting advice online. Some say that "oriented towards" pertains to directional senses and "oriented for" describes purpose. Others say only "oriented towards" is correct for both senses.

Could someone help me understand the difference? (Non-native speaker here.)

For example, "Madeline has been oriented for/towards some hospitality services besides her managerial duties."

Comment: In your example, if M was trained *for* those functions, she got orientation sessions, which **oriented** her **for** those duties. If self-directed *towards* those duties, she was **oriented towards** them besides her managerial one.

Comment: Some cars have rearview mirrors that automatically orient **for** daytime or nighttime  driving.